# Android Eclipse > Graphical Layout: How to Set Default Layout = Nexus 7 or Not 2 for every XML layout I open to look same in IDE and Device

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, graphical-layout-editor

Is there any way in Android Eclipse that whenever I open layout/any_xml_file.xml in Eclipse it should have Nexus 7 or Note 2 (Custom defined device) as default (so I won't select manually from only available devices/sizes) in Graphical Layout GUI so even if I do not deploy on that device it should look perfectly same on device and in IDE itself prior to build and run?

It will save time to test on Kindle Fire, Note 2, Galaxy S3, Nexus 7, Nexus 10 etc instead of deploying on each of the device.

In short, solution should be for:
**1. Setting default device for Graphical Layout
2. Adding Custom device (or screen size) in that list for Graphical Layout**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can set it by creating different layout folders.
layout-mdpi
layout-hdpi
layout-xhdpi
layout-xxhdpi
That way, the layout editor will keep in mind, which layout you use for which screen size/device. Hope this helps